# SpringSource Tool Suite tc Server Weaving Error

Tags: java, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Environment : Windows XP, SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) 2.3.2, Roo 1.0.0, Java 1.6.0_10

I'm evaluating Roo and have created a Roo project with one Entity. Starting the tc server shows the below error in the log. My entity is StbTestResult. The app works, but I'm wondering why the error message appears?
Thanks,
Steve

[TomcatAspectJWeavingClassLoader@97eded] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
[TomcatAspectJWeavingClassLoader@97eded] error aspect 'org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl' woven into 'com.canoe.dce.domain.StbTestResult_Roo_Entity' must be defined to the weaver (placed on the aspectpath, or defined in an aop.xml file if using LTW).
[TomcatAspectJWeavingClassLoader@97eded] error aspect 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect' woven into 'com.canoe.dce.domain.StbTestResult_Roo_Entity' must be defined to the weaver (placed on the aspectpath, or defined in an aop.xml file if using LTW).